# How to tell if spamc in .procmailrc is reading user_prefs?

Tags: email-server, spamassassin

I have some mail accounts on a Postfix server on Ubuntu 18.04 that have the following in the .procmailrc files in their home directories:

```
# LOGFILE=$HOME/procmail.log
SHELL=/bin/sh

:0fw
| spamc

:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
$HOME/SPAM

:0
! xxx@xxxx.com
```

In `/etc/procmailrc` I have:

```
ORGMAIL=${HOME}/Maildir/
DEFAULT=${ORGMAIL}
```

`/etc/default/spamassassin` has:

```
OPTIONS="--create-prefs --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir"
```

`/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf` has:

```
allow_user_rules       1
```

Looking at the spam scoring in the postfix logs, I suspect that individual `.spamassassin/user_prefs` files aren't being read. There are no permissions or other errors, but custom spam scoring doesn't seem to be honoured.

How can I find out if they are or not?

---

**EDIT**: As per @A.B's comment, I have tried using `inotifywait -c user_prefs` to establish whether the file is being read. It says the event on the file (which happens on receiving an email) is ACCESS. That seems from the man page to be different from READ.

Why isn't spamassassin reading the file?

Comment: [`inotifywait`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/inotifywait.1.html)?

Comment: Ah, good idea. It says `user_prefs` gets an OPEN event though, not an ACCESS (that is, read) event. Hm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, do you get the error “spamd: still running as root: user not specified with -u, not found, or set to root, falling back to nobody” in your mail log?

If so try putting

```
DROPPRIVS=yes
```

in /etc/procmailrc

Comment: No errors in the logs I'm afraid. The mystery remains.